# Irrlicht fails to create a GLX context when passed a SDL2-created Window

Tags: opengl, x11, sdl-2, irrlicht

**I am trying to get Irrlicht to be using a window I created using SDL2 under X11, but it fails within Irrlicht at `GLXCreateWindow`.**

On my box the following MCVE reproduces the issue:

```
#include <irrlicht/irrlicht.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_syswm.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        800, 600,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (!window)
    {
        return false;
    }

    SDL_SysWMinfo wm_info;
    SDL_VERSION(&wm_info.version);

    if (!SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &wm_info))
    {
        return false;
    }

    irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters params;
    params.DeviceType = irr::EIDT_BEST;
    params.DriverType = irr::video::EDT_OPENGL;
    params.WindowSize = { 800, 600 };
    params.WindowId = reinterpret_cast<void*>(wm_info.info.x11.window);
    irr::createDeviceEx(params);
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Irrlicht Engine version 1.9.0
Linux 4.16.16-1-ck #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 19 20:30:54 CEST 2018 x86_64
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  31 (X_GLXCreateWindow)
  Serial number of failed request:  364
  Current serial number in output stream:  365
```

If you comment out the `WindowId` set Irrlicht will create its own window, which succeeds.

```
Irrlicht Engine version 1.9.0
Linux 4.16.16-1-ck #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 19 20:30:54 CEST 2018 x86_64
Using renderer: OpenGL 4.4
Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.23.0, 4.16.16-1-ck, LLVM 7.0.0): X.Org
OpenGL driver version is 1.2 or better.
GLSL version: 4.4
```

I tried to troubleshoot the issue but unfortunately I have no idea how to debug X11 errors like those. However, as per [the docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glXCreateWindow.xml), "BadMatch is generated if win was not created with a visual that corresponds to config, or if `config` does not support rendering to windows (i.e., `GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE` does not contain `GLX_WINDOW_BIT`)."

Some of my attempts included, to no avail:

- Setting `params.Bits` to `16`, `24` and `32`.
- Using Irrlicht 1.7 and 1.9.0 SVN (built as of today).
- Setting the Irrlicht render backend to software rendering *works*, as it doesn't try to create a GLX context.
- Setting `params.LoggingLevel = ELL_DEBUG;` as it would hopefully print useful info on the problem, but doesn't.
- Setting `params.IgnoreInput = true;`.
- Toggling the `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag in `SDL_CreateWindow`.
- Using `apitrace` to try to figure out details on errors, or at least obviously invalid parameters, but I couldn't find it out, especially as it doesn't seem to simply track X11 calls, only GLX and OpenGL calls.

Comment: Quite hard to debug, but in that case in is caused by irrlicht trying to create `GLXWindow` on top of presented window with different visual id than initial window that SDL have created. I honestly have no idea why it even attempts to create said window (except when maybe window wasn't created with GL capabilities), creating context is enough (and even that probably should be delegated to SDL), and I see no possible fix without modifying irrlicht source. As a proof of concept, you can get visual id it tries to use in debugger or printf, and `export SDL_VIDEO_X11_VISUALID` to that value.

Comment: ...or just stomp out `UseGLXWindow` in `CIrrDeviceLinux::createWindow()` to force it to create context instead of creating window. Not sure if it is rarely tested part or actually intended thing.